# Question on the Html.ActionLink helper - Specifically the syntax for the object routeValues parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

So I understand the use of the ActionLink HTML helper, as well as most of the parameters.  I am still in the process of wrapping my head around the complete range of uses for the object routeValues parameter.

However, my question is that it seems for the routeValues parameter you could specify the object as either the existing object from the ViewData dictionary:

```
Html.ActionLink("Some Text", "Edit", Model.ProductId);
```

or you can use object initializing syntax:

```
Html.ActionLink("Some Text", "Edit", new { Model.ProductId });
```

My 2 questions, are

A) what is the defining reason to use one over another?  I have a hard time understanding why you have to initialize a new one since you already have the property with the correct value in the Model.

B) I understand instantiating a new object (i.e. var someVar = new SomeObject()), but what are you defining in the above example ( new { Model.ProductID }) and your specifying a property?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, both of those are incorrect.  When you specify an object that isn't a RouteValueDictionary (typically an anonymous object), it transfers the property/value pairs into the dictionary by using reflection over the properties of the object.  In neither case you use will you get an object that translates into a RouteValueDictionary containing an `id` key with an associated value.  In the second case, <strike>I don't think you even have legal syntax</strike> it won't map correctly onto the id parameter given the default routes.  The syntax that you want is:

```
Html.ActionLink("Some Text", "Edit", new { id = Model.ProductId } );
```

You're creating an anonymous object with an `id` property whose value is `Model.ProductId`. This will result in a RouteValueDictionary with an `id` key that maps onto the value of `Model.ProductId`.

Comment: THanks for the explanation - So it is an anonymous object.  Yes, the second one is legal (since A) it works, and B) it is straight from Steve Sanderson).

Comment: @phgtech - but it won't result in an `id` parameter, it will result in a `ProductId` parameter, which may be correct but isn't typical for routing in MVC.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  MVC/C#/Programming is all new to me, so this is one of those facts of the trade I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to send other values to the controller action

Example:

```
Html.ActionLink("Some Text", "Edit", new { id=Model.ProductId, myotherValue=1 });
```

And your control action is something like this

```
Public ActionResult Edit(int id, int myotherValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

B) syntax `new { id = 1, name = "11" }` means "create anonymous object". During build process compiler finds all such usages and creates classes with unreadable names in your assembly like this:

```
class AnonymousType`1
{
    int id {get; private set};
    int name {get; private set};
}
```

then all references change to code like this `` new <>AnonymousType`1{ id = 1, name = "11" } ``
*It is just a description of how it works, generated code is a little more complex.*

A) So you see, that `Model.ProductId` is int, and `new { Model.ProductId }` is instance of some type, generated by compiler.

You could examine this using Reflector. More info about [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)